# Topological isomorphism vs isometric isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We say that:

- $T:(X,\|\cdot\|_X)\rightarrow (Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ is a *isometric isomorphism* if it is a linear isomorphism, and it is an isometry, that is $\|T(x)\|_Y=\|x\|_X\quad \forall x\in X;$
- $T:(X,\|\cdot\|_X)\rightarrow (Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ is a *topological isomorphism* if it is a linear isomorphism and $T$ is continuous with continuous inverse.

My question is: is any isometric isomorphism a topological isomorphism? Since $T$ is an isometry, in particular $\|T(x)\|\leq \|x\|\quad \forall x\in X$, so $T$ is continuous. But what can I say for the inverse? Is it continuous too?

In fact, my problem is to prove that if $E$ is a reflexive n.v.s then $E$ is Banach. So it is sufficient to prove that $J_E:E\rightarrow E''$ is a topological isomorphism, but, by definition of reflexive space, I know that $J_E$ is a isometric isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to show that the inverse of an isometry between normed spaces is an isometry. Since an isometry is continuous, you're done.

Comment: Is it necessary that both spaces are Banach? Because I only know that one of them is complete.

Comment: @Claretta Oh, sorry! I wanted to type *normed* and wrote *Banach*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that an isometric isomorphism is continuous with continuous inverse, then the way you start is "Given an isometric isomorphism $T$, a point $x$ and an $\epsilon >0$, ..." and then you use the isometric property of $T$ and the triangle inequality to find your $\delta$, both for $T$ and its inverse.